# How can I remove class from Slick Slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I've been trying to use slick slider and I am running into a small issue. I have two sections where I want to use the slider. First one is just the "fade" effect with one picture and the second one is testimonial slider. Now the issue is if I want to have a margin between my testimonials and I use:

```
 .slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 10px;
  }
```

[See picture of margin between the testimonials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXUJq.png)

HTML Markup -

```
    <div class="slider">
    <div class="testimonial-container">
        <div class="testimonial-img">
            <img src="images/face.jpg" alt="face">
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial-text">
            <h3>This is the only Norskkurs to take in Stavanger if value for 
                money and truly progressing with
                the Norwegian are important factors for you.
            </h3>
            <strong>Jessica Morris</strong>
            <p>A1/A2 Student</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-container">
        <div class="testimonial-img">
            <img src="images/face.jpg" alt="face">
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial-text">
            <h3>Very hands on and animated. Relaxed atmosphere which is
                perfect for feeling comfortable in a new language setting.
            </h3>
            <strong>Helen Brian</strong>
            <p>A2 Student</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-container">
        <div class="testimonial-img">
            <img src="images/face.jpg" alt="face">
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial-text">
            <h3>This course is a wonderful journey with lots of fun and 
                activities towards the goal. It's a well
                designed course for learning.
            </h3>
            <strong>Chidabaram Harikumar</strong>
            <p>A1/A2/B1 Student</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-container">
        <div class="testimonial-img">
            <img src="images/face.jpg" alt="face">
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial-text">
            <h3>It is first language course which I have lasted more than one month :) . It means alot to me. They
                teach with both their heart and brain.
            </h3>
            <strong>Amir Ghaderian</strong>
            <p>A2/B1 Student</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-container">
        <div class="testimonial-img">
            <img src="images/face.jpg" alt="face">
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial-text">
            <h3>One of the best thing which I have done in my life is to join Norskkurs in LNS.It's a great place to
                learn the language with good people.

            </h3>
            <strong>Dayanand Mohanasundram</strong>
            <p>A1/A2 Student</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now with my next "fade" slide I don't want the margin but it will still add the same .slick-slide properties to all the slides I use.

Is there anyway I can only apply this to one slide or remove this class/property from other slides?

In short, I only need margin between testimonials slide and not the other one. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a class testimonials to the testimonials slider and add margin to this class.

```
  .testimonial-slide {
  margin: 0px 10px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but It doesn't work... I can only get the margin between testimonials with : .slick-slide class

Comment: Why? You have 3 slides. All of this, have a div container? You just need to add a extra class for the testimonial container and style this with adding margin.

Can you share more code please? What does your HTML code look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest updating your HTML structure if it's not updated. You can use BEM https://en.bem.info/methodology/ in order to not fall in such traps.

If you have 4 sliders you might have the following HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider__slides">
      <div class="slider__slide"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-testimonials">
    <div class="slider__slides">
      <div class="slider__slide"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-faq">
    <div class="slider__slides">
      <div class="slider__slide"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-people">
    <div class="slider__slides">
      <div class="slider__slide"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So there won't be a problem to style each `slider__slide` per slider.

`.slider-testimonials .slider__slide { margin: 0 10px; }`

Then, the above margin won't be applied to the other sliders.

If you need to share a style among all `slider__slide` elements.

You can do the following:

`.slider__slide { box-shadow: 0 0 0 black; }` for example.

I hope that helps.